# Get second highest values from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

| id | conn_id | read_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2010-02-21 |
| 2 | 1 | 2011-02-21 |
| 3 | 2 | 2011-02-21 |
| 4 | 2 | 2013-02-21 |
| 5 | 2 | 2014-02-21 |

I want the second highest read_date for particular 'conn_id's i.e. I want a group by on conn_id. Please help me figure this out.

Comment: What do you want to do when there are two identical maximal values for the date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution for a particular `conn_id` :

```
select max (read_date) from my_table
where conn_id=1
and read_date<(
   select max (read_date) from my_table
   where conn_id=1
)
```

If you want to get it for all `conn_id` using `group by`, do this:

```
select t.conn_id, (select max(i.read_date) from my_table i
where i.conn_id=t.conn_id and i.read_date<max(t.read_date))
from my_table t group by conn_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but can't you modify it for the generic case?

Comment: It should print second highest 'read_date's for all the unique 'conn_id's.

Comment: But could you please tell me why this query, 'select *,max(read_date) as prev from my_table where read_date<(select max(read_date) from my_table) group by conn_id;', is not working. It gives correct output for only the maximum conn_id. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Following answer should work in MSSQL :

```
select id,conn_id,read_date  from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by conn_id order by read_date desc) as RN 
from my_table
)
where RN =2
```

There is an intresting article on use of rank functions in MySQL here :
 [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If your table design as ID - date matching (ie a big id always a big date), you can group by id, otherwise do the following:

```
$sql_max = '(select conn_id, max(read_date) max_date from tab group by 1) as tab_max';

$sql_max2 = "(select tab.conn_id,max(tab.read_date) max_date2 from tab, $sql_max
where tab.conn_id = tab_max.conn_id and tab.read_date < tab_max.max_date 
group by 1) as tab_max2";

$sql = "select tab.* from tab, $sql_max2 
where tab.conn_id = tab_max2.conn_id and tab.read_date = tab_max2.max_date2";
```